# Scale paths & shapes when <svg> changes size

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael

I am using Raphael to draw some shapes on the page. The `<svg>` is already set to `{ width:100%; height:600px }` and that is working fine. As I resize the browser width, I would like to adjust the shapes inside the `<svg>` to fit the new width. Ideally this should happen automatically; it just seems wrong to have to manually scale each shape and path on window.resize.

I know that percentages are illegal in the path string but this is essentially what I am looking to do:

```
var r = Raphael('container', '100%', 600);
r.path("M0,0 L0,0 55%,0 100%,61z")
```

Comment: Call Dmitry Baranovskiy?

Comment: @AshwinGanesh Why didn't I think of that?! Do you have his number? :)

Comment: Perhaps [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322660/scaling-svg-raphael-js-like-an-swf) would be relevant to your question?

Comment: @raina77ow That looks promising. I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff, International call - Adobe Australia - Operator - Dmitry :P Just kidding. I have faced a similar problem `onresize`, ended up writing separate scaling functions. I have been searching the net for a quite a bit now. Nothing promising. However, raina77ow's suggestion seems to be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You should first use an absolute width and height for both the paper and the path. You will also need to set the viewBox on the paper using `setViewBox()`.

From there, you set the width of `div#container` to 100% using CSS. You may also need to set `body` and `html` as such:

```
body,
html {
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```